# How to determine if now(utc) is within the range of the given days of the week and times of the day in ISO 8601 format

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timespan, timezone-offset

I run into this question of how to determine if `DateTime.UtcNow` (e.g. 2018-01-01T20:00:00Z) falls within the given range of days and times that are in another timezone. There are no specific dates given, just the days of the week, and the time of the day. The given time is in ISO 8601 standard format.

To simplify this question, it can be how to check if a UTC time is within business hours in China.

For example, the given day and time range is given by someone form China in time zone +08:00, it can be: `FromDayOfWeek = "Friday", FromTimeOfDay = "17:00:00+8:00", ToDayOfWeek = "Monday", ToTimeOfWeek = "08:00:00+8:00".` I need to determine if "now" in China is sometime between the given range (Friday 17:00:00+8:00 - Monday 08:00:00+8:00).

I'm stuck at how to convert the DateTime and get the day of the week in that local time, since 2018-01-01T20:00:00Z is Monday in UK, but at the same time, since China is +08:00, it is already Tuesday in China.

My approach:

```
// parse the time to get the zone first (+08:00)
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("-08:00");

// Create a custom time zone since the time zone id is not given, and cannot be searched by SearchTimeZoneById
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(zoneId, ts, displayName, standardName);
DateTime localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Date.UtcNow, tzi);

String localDay = localDateTime.DayOfWeek;

// Determine if localDay is between FromDayOfWeek and ToDayOfWeek
// cast the days to integers from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)  
// create an array of days in integar days = [5, 6, 7, 1]
// if days.contains(localDays), check the times
...
```

Can anyone suggest some better solutions? I am not sure if mine works, and there are holes in how to deal with Day Light Saving time, since the zone will change, and how to check the time range. I am new to C#, any suggestions of libraries I can use is great!

Comment: I would probably convert the "from" and "to" to min/max UTC datetimes, and then compare them to the current UTC datetime.

Comment: If you need to handle more than just this instance (or even if you don't) You may want to take a look at the nodatime library, especially given your comments about handling daylight savings properly. I've had great luck with it for similar problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting both start and end times from UTC, just convert the other time into UTC

```
    TimeZoneInfo chinaTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(zoneID, TimeSpan.Parse("-08:00"), displayName, standardName);

    DateTime FromTime = new DateTime(2018, 0, 19, 13, 0, 0); // year, month, day, hour, minute, second : Friday 1pm
    DateTime ToTime = new DateTime(2018, 0, 21, 1, 0, 0); // year, month, day, hour, minute, second : Monday 1am

    DateTime nowinUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime nowInChina = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowinUTC, chinaTimeZone);

    if(FromTime< nowInChina && ToTime> nowInChina)
    {
        // Time is within the from and two times
    }
```

Comment: `DateTime` already has [comparison operator overrides](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#L1279-L1293) which uses the Ticks value. You don't need `FromTime.Ticks < nowInChina.Ticks`, you can just compare the two DateTime objects: `FromTime < nowInChina`.

Comment: The FromTime and ToTime are not DateTime objects, they only have days of the week and time. My question or confusion here is how to compare the day of the week with the consideration of time offset, and daylight saving. If the range is given as date and time, the problem would be a lot easier.

Comment: @Tomatojam, the point is that the simplest way to do what you're asking is to convert your From/To dates into DateTimes and use the built-in comparators against UtcNow.

Comment: @Immersive, thanks for clarifying! Let me rephrase my question better, this part of code happens in an iterative situation, in which I need to be constantly checking if the current time falls within the given day and time range. The from/to dates are not set, they can be every Friday to Monday. Do you mean that the easier way is to create new DateTime object according to the day and time? How do you determine the date (month and day)?

Comment: @Tomatojam Are you saying the From/To dates change per iteration?  Are they specific dates, or just 'days of the week''?

Comment: @Immersive Yes, the dates (year, month, day) will change per iteration. The are not specific dates, they are just days of the week (Friday, Saturday, Sunday, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments on @Moffen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50421241/342842), you only want to check if `Now` is within a specific `DayOfWeek` range:

```
public void CheckAll(List<SomeClass> spans)
{
    var chinaTZ = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(zoneID, TimeSpan.Parse("-08:00"), displayName, standardName);

    var nowInChina = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, chinaTZ);

    foreach ( var span in spans )
    {
        if (InRange(nowInChina, span.startDay, span.endDay))
            // Do something on success 
            // Check for valid times here
            ;
        else
            // Do something on Failure
            ;
    }
}
public bool InRange(DateTime dateToCheck, DayOfWeek startDay, DayOfWeek endDay)
{
    // Initialise as one day prior because first action in loop is to increment current
    var current = (int)startDay - 1;

    do
    {
        // Move to next day, wrap back to Sunday if went past Saturday
        current = (current + 1) % 7;

        if (dateToCheck.DayOfWeek == (DayOfWeek)current)
            return true;

    } while (current != (int)endDay);

    return false;
}
```